# Blazor Wasm Uncaught Type Error - Failed to Fetch

Tags: certificate, blazor-webassembly

I think I have broken my PC/Visual Studio/IIS by playing around with my Certificates (don't judge me, I had good reason).  Now, none of my Blazor WASM projects will run, even a newly created one.  Here is the error, which appears about a million times in the output:

```
Uncaught TypeError TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at loadResourceWithoutCaching (localhost꞉7098/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:52251)
    at loadResourceWithCaching (localhost꞉7098/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:51982)
    --- Promise.then ---
    at <anonymous> (localhost꞉7098/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:39163)
    at <anonymous> (localhost꞉7098/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:39140)
    at start (localhost꞉7098/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:46018)
    at Vt (localhost꞉7098/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:62202)
    --- await ---
    at <anonymous> (localhost꞉7098/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:63609)
    at <anonymous> (localhost꞉7098/_framework/blazor.webassembly.js:1:63686)
```

And from the browser console:

[image: Browser Console]

Plenty of results for this when Googling, but they mostly refer to deployments on servers etc.  This is literally creating a new project and running it on my local PC.

I have "repaired" both IIS and VS.

Fully appreciate this issue is probably of my making and I really don't deserve any help from anyone, but any advice would be gratefully received.